# Mixture probability from mixtures of Cauchy distributions

Tags: probability, estimation, inference, order-statistics, cauchy-distribution

Suppose that $Z \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p)$ and $Y_1,Y_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be Gaussian random variables and let all of them be independent. Suppose I am given samples from the following random variable $X$ defined as
$$
X= Z + \frac{Y_1}{ Y_2}.
$$
Notice that $X$ is a Cauchy centred at $1$ if $Z=1$ and $0$ if $Z=0$. So my question is whether we can infer the probability $p$ from samples $X_1,\ldots,X_n$? I am wondering if there is a solution to this problem. Of course, one could use EM to solve this but I want a consistent estimator for $p$.

I found on the Wikipedia article on Cauchy distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#cite_note-rothenberg-17 that the parameter estimation from Cauchy samples is usually done by taking the central mean of order statistics ($0.24$ fraction, to be precise). But the order statistics for the mixtures can be tricky and no closed form expressions exist.

Comment: As the Cauchy distr. is symmetric, you could use the sum of the signs of $X$ as an estimator of $p$. So $p = \sum_j I(X_j>0) / n$.

Comment: I don't see a reason why that would estimate $p$. Have you taken into consideration the Cauchy centered at $1$?

Comment: @Semoi: But your idea is very close. The cdf of $X$ is given by $F_X(x)=pF(x-1)+(1-p)F(x)$ where $F$ is the cdf of Cauchy. Using this we can compute $F_X(0.5)$ and from this we can solve for $p$.

Comment: What does the phrase "*central mean*" mean? I've never heard it before

Comment: @Glen_b: If we have $2n+1$ samples and they are ordered into $X_{(-n)},\ldots,X_{(0)},\ldots,X_{(n)}$, the central mean refers to the quantity $\frac{\sum_{i=-k}^k X_{(i)}}{2k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. That's normally called a *trimmed mean*, or (more rarely) a truncated mean. But it doesn't normally require an odd number of observations. If $k = (n+1)/2$ it would be the mid-mean or interquartile mean.

Comment: The average of the middle 24% of the data (which is the optimal trimmed mean for the location parameter of the Cauchy) corresponds to a 38% trimmed mean (removing the 38% largest and 38% smallest values before averaging)

Comment: @Glen_b: Correct. I was wondering if a similar trimmed mean technique can be employed for mixtures of Cauchy and hence asked this question.

Comment: The trimmed mean in the Cauchy is being used as an estimate of location; and an estimate of location, a trimmed mean for a 50-50 mixture of components with equal scale and with a similar gap (i.e. component peaks at 0.375 and 0.625 quantiles) would probably be reasonable but you  may want to use a larger portion of the data in the mean - perhaps nearer 50%. (NB: You wouldn't estimate $p$ itself by using the trimmed mean; if $p$ isn't 1/2 but you know $p$ you can probably design a weighted-trimmed mean that's reasonable as a location estimator.)

Comment: @whuber Hopefully the comment better explains what I was trying to get at. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why is EM assumed to be inconsistent? This is a numerical method to derive a maximum likelihood estimator, which is consistent in this case.